# I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS frequently having issue with boot and stuck in initial loading ramdisk

Tags: 18.04

I have purchased a Dell Vostro laptop with ubuntu a month ago and I having booting issue frequently for last few days it got stuck up in booting.
I have to boot it in recovery mode, can someone help.

Comment: Do you have any error message while trying to boot on Ubuntu in *normal* mode?

Comment: No, after the dell logo screen its going gnu grub version 2.02 screen. When I start ubuntu from there it got stuck up(sometimes in black screen and sometimes in loading ramdisk).